# Deployment error in Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to deploy my application in weblogic server but it is throwing the below exception

> weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException  at
>   weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptBytes(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptString(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:187)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.internal.encryption.ClearOrEncryptedService.decrypt(ClearOrEncryptedService.java:96)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace Caused By:
>
> weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException  at
>   weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptBytes(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptString(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:187)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.internal.encryption.ClearOrEncryptedService.decrypt(ClearOrEncryptedService.java:96)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>
> Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Could someone please help me out as this has not happened before and I'm not able to find any info online.

thanks